# Upgrading PHP 5.3 to 5.5

Tags: php, cakephp, upgrade

My website is running in CakePHP 1.3 and PHP 5.3. I got a mail from the host that they will be upgrading PHP to 5.5. How will it affect my website? What all changes should I make to keep my website working in PHP 5.5?

Comment: This is a very general question.  Have you run into any specific issues with upgrading?

Comment: They have given me a future date for upgrading. Just wanted to confirm that the website will continue to work.

Comment: Why not install your app on a machine running 5.5 to see what happens. Spoiler: probably nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

This won't change much, you'll have updated functions available and certain old ones may be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a large PHP update, for a list of changes look here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php
http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.changes.php